# Detect event in Google Marker

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, dom-events

In my code, how can I get the name of the User that someone clicked on in the marker?
Currently my code has:

```
 function createMarker(point, user, studytopic) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      var currUser = user;
      var html = '<b>' + user + '</b> <br/>' + studytopic + '<br/>' +
      '<a href="javascript:showContactSB()"> Contact ' + user + '</a>' ;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }
```

currUser is a global field, however, it's not updated every time I click on a different marker in Google maps. 
Basically what I'm looking for is a event to fire when a link (id=contactSBLink) within any marker is clicked.  I want it to get the Username(which is a link) to pass the user variable to another function. 
I'm not sure what's the best way to go about to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the user `u` to the `javascript:showContactSB(u)`. This is an exercise in setting quotes properly:

```
var u = "'" + user + "'"; 
var html = '<b>' + user + '</b> <br/>' + studytopic + '<br/>' +
    '<a href="javascript:showContactSB(' + u + ')"> Contact ' + user + '</a>' ;
```

Now, you get the user in the click-function:

```
function showContactSB(user) {
    alert("Hi " + user);
}
```

BTW, I would recommend you to upgrade to Google Maps v3.

Comment: Hi Jiri - 
I am not passing this showContactSB function.  I'd like to send it to another function.  However the function does not need to be called in this portion.  That's why I wanted to set it up as a global variable.  However, the issue with setting up the global variable is that, it doesn't update everytime  I click on another marker.  Basically what I need is, getUser of every marker that gets clicked.

Comment: I do not completetely understand your problem. In my proposal the function `showContactSB(user)` is called each time when the user clicks the link. This function gets the data `user` and can do anything with it, e.g. assign it to a global variable, or anything else.